# Magento 2 CRUD by Alan Storm question

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

I'm working through this tutorial http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/

When I reach the point Magento 2 Factory Objects, confusion embraces me as the code in my local project starts to differ from the one in tutorial. Maybe the tutorial was not updated for some time.
It says there should be Pulsestorm\ToDoCrud\Model\**TodoItemFactory** class, but I don't have it.

When I run my page, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Pulsestorm\\ToDoCrud\\Block\\Main::__construct() must be an instance of Pulsestorm\\ToDoCrud\\Model\\TodoItemFactory, array given
```

This second argument is in the code below, but I am apparently missing the class file itself.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Pulsestorm\ToDoCrud\Model\TodoItemFactory $toDoFactory
    )
```

What shall I do? 
Do I have to create the class file manually?
Does TodoItemRepository has something to do with this?

Comment: Remove `var/generation` folder.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!  Magento 2's not a system that's built to easily teach newcomers things.  You may want to work your way through the object system/manager series (http://alanstorm.com/series/magento-2-object-system/) first.  We mention factory generation there -- specifically in this article: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_instance_objects/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 will automatically generate Factory classes for you upon request (or at time of compilation).  You need to clear your `var/generation` folder and visit the page to automatically generate the missing file.

Most likely Alan's blog hasn't been updated as Magento has progressed and added improvements to modules.

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Unfortunately there was no mention about it in the tutorial.